# Addition or subtraction of speeds?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can we also take $(x+15)$ and $(x-15)$ in the following problem?

Problem:
The speed of a boat in still water is $15$ km/h. It goes $30$ km upstream and return downstream to the original point in $4$ hours $30$ minutes. Find the speed of the stream(in km/h).

Solution: Let $x$ be the speed of the water!
Then, going upstream is at speed $15-x$
And going downstream is at speed $15+x$
So we have $\frac{30}{15+x} + \frac{30}{15-x} = 4.5$.
How do we solve this ? Let's combine the fractions
$$\frac{30}{15-x} + \frac{30}{15+x} = \frac{900}{225-x^2} = 4.5$$
Now we can multiply by the denominator
$$900 = 4.5(225-x^2)$$ $$200 = 225-x^2$$$$x^2 = 25$$So the speed of the river is 5.

In the above solution, can we also take $(x+15)$ and $(x-15)?$

I have asked many people for the explanation, but no one has given a satisfactory explanation to me.

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: In upstream the speed should be $15-x$

Comment: If the boat is traveling upstream, it is moving against the current, so the boat's speed should be $15 - x$; if the boat is traveling downstream, it is moving with the current, so its speed should be $15 + x$.

Comment: Take $(x+15)$ and $(x-15)$ and see what happens

Comment: Would you explain why we can't take $x-15?$

Comment: The point of this question is that you have a boat that has a certain speed in still water, and when it goes upstream, it moves against the current, so the net speed is decreased by the speed of the water; hence $15-x$; if your stream moves at 3kmph ($x=3$), then you move upstream at 12kmph, not at -12kmph (that would mean it's actually moving further downstream). $x-15$ doesn't measure anything meaningful in this context. $x+15$ and $15+x$ are the same so it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I have taken $(x+15)$ and $(x-15)$ but didn't get the answer.If we take $(x+15)$ and (15-x),$ that mean speed of boat is more than the speed of water.But how to know it.Does anyone has a better explanation?

Comment: @Debrogli tbh $15-x$ is the correct expression even when if the speed of the current is greater than that of the boat (although the fact that the boat makes both trips successfully implies that can't be the case). Just that if $x>15$, you can't solve the problem using this equality (because then the boat actually never makes it back upstream).

Answer (score 2):

If we take $x+15$ instead of $15+x$ nothing happens. But if we take $x-15$ instead of $15-x$ a lot happens.

We usually consider the speed of river smaller than the boat. River usually flows at a slow rate. So in your case we assumed that the speed of boat $>$ speed of river.

However if anyone is making an assumption then it should be mentioned as in case of floods or maybe when the river is violent, it flows with a much faster speed. So if in this case, the speed of boat is less than the river then the boat won't we able to go upstream.

Answer (score 2):

Given that our boat manages to complete the trip, we know that its speed is greater than the speed of the stream (otherwise it would simply fail to move forward!).

Thus, it must be $x<15$.

By taking $x-15\lt0$ as its speed you are violating that assumption, ending up with $x^2=-25$ which simply cannot hold.